# Espacios en blanco

Tags: java

Estoy quitando los espacios de una cadena de texto y he utilizado esto :

```
for (int x = 0; x < frase.length(); x++) {
    System.out.println(frase.replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

y me sale esto por pantalla:

[image: espacios]

Mi idea es que quite los espacios a partir de 2 espacios consecutivos. Si yo introduzco:

```
Hola  caracola
```

(nótese los 2 espacios) quiero borrar solamente un espacio, no los dos espacios.

Con el código anterior lo quita, pero me sale `holacaracola` todo junto porque borro de más. ¿Cómo podria poner un espacio pero sin afectar al codigo anterior?

Comment: ¿2 tabuladiones, 2 espacios o 2 caracteres de espacios en blanco? ¿y qué debería hacer con espacios al principio o al final de la frase?

Comment: O `.replaceAll("^[ \\t]+|[ \\t]+(\\pP|$)|([ \\t])\\2+", "$1$2")`, pero todo depende de qué quiera hacer

Comment: @rencinas A mí me recuerda también a mis inicios :D. Y sí, la verdad que para ser nueva, están muy bien organizadas y claras sus preguntas.

Comment: @Mariano Me refiero a 2 espacios. Si yo introduzco : Hola -- (-representa 2 espacios) borrar solamente un espacio, no los dos espacios como he hecho yo. Por eso me sale holacaracola porque borro de más. Muchas gracias por ayudarme :)

Comment: @rencinas jajaja Me está costando entender bien el lenguaje y a la minima lo pregunto todo. Gracias por tu respuesta, voy con probar .trim() que indicas :)

Comment: @bpico si solo quieres borrar dos espacios por que no pusiste `replace("(dos espacios)", " ");` ?

Comment: @bpico Por "tabulaciones" se daba a entender un `"\t"`, no un espacio. Modifiqué la pregunta para aclararlo.

Comment: @lois6b Eso no funcionaría en el caso de 3 espacios consecutivos.

Comment: @bpico Borré mi respuesta ya que vi el nuevo edit y vi que te referías a espacios y no a tabulaciones. De todas formas, en caso de que en alguna ocasión necesites borrar tabulaciones en vez de espacios, entonces tendrás que referirte a `\t` para eliminarlas. Un saludo:)

Comment: @lois6b ¡¡muchas gracias, me refería a esto!!!

Comment: @bpico te refieres a mi comentario de replace 2 espacios por 1 espacio? fue un comentario idiota tal y como recalca Mariano. Con 3 espacios te dejaría 2 ... considero mejor mi respuesta

Comment: @Mariano perdona por referirme a tabulaciones en vez de espacios.

Comment: @Error404 Muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta :)

Comment: @lois6b Si, he probado lo que me has puesto en el comentario anterior  System.out.println(frase.replaceAll("(  ) ", ""));  Me he dado cuenta que depende los espacios que introduzcas en los () pero imagino que poniendo 3 espacios ya seria suficiente, te has acercado bastante. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @bpico lo que decía del .trim() elimina todos los espacios en blanco del inicio y el final de un string, ej: "    buenas tardes    ".trim() = "buenas tardes" El espacio de en medio se mantiene, pero los de los extremos se eliminan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tal y como indica esta [página](http://programming.guide/java/removing-duplicate-whitespace.html):

```
tuString= tuString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("lorem  ipsum   dolor \n sit.".replaceAll("\\s+", " ")); // reemplaza `\s+` por un espacio
```

Sale:

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit.
```

Ya que:

> `\s+` es una expresion regular. `\s` coincidiendo con un espacio, tabulacion, linea nueva, intro ...

Entonces, los caracteres especificados quedan sustituidos por un espacio

Comment: Gracias por contestar a mi pregunta, lo que me refería es que lo quitara sin utilizar \s .Pero de todas maneras, lo pobraré :)

Comment: @bpico ¿si no quieres usar `\s` entonces qué otra manera buscas? ¿Tiene que ser necesariamente con una expresión regular?

Answer (score 2):

La expresión regular `" {2,}"` coincide con 2 o más espacios consecutivos, lo cual permite reemplazarlo por 1 solo:

```java
String frase = "hola    hola     caracola    !";
frase = frase.replaceAll(" {2,}"," ");
```

Resultado:

```
hola hola caracola !
```

Demo:

<kbd>[Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/9TSrkk)</kbd>

---

Si se quieren reemplazar 2 o más tabulaciones consecutivas por 1, se usaría:

```java
String frase = "hola\t\thola\t\tcaracola!";
frase = frase.replaceAll("\\t{2,}","\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

He aquí una solución sin utilizar una expresión regular:

**Código**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hola  caracola  !";
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int dest = 1;
    for (int src = 1; src < chars.length; src++) {
        if (chars[src] != ' ' || chars[src - 1] != ' ') {
            chars[dest++] = chars[src];
        }
    }
    String result = new String(chars, 0, dest);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Salida**

```
Hola caracola !
```

Comment: Tu respuesta también me sirve. Lo que la frase se tiene que pedir por teclado. Muchas gracias!!