# Quitar el espacio en blanco a una cadena resultante

Tags: java

Hola tengo esta duda:

Suprimir los espacios en blanco de una cadena que se introduce por teclado. El resultado
debe quedar en otra cadena. No se pueden utilizar métodos replace.

Comment: Tienes que quitar los espacios del principio y del final o también los que haya entre las palabras? Qué has pensado y qué has intentado? Te ha dado algún fallo? Por favor, amplía tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Puedes leer [ask] para ver como editarla.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32488/espacios-en-blanco?rq=1 ahi hay información util para ti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar un bucle `for`, creas una cadena nueva y concatenas carácter por carácter en esa cadena nueva(antes debes inicializarla ej: `result = ""`).Luego compruebas cada carácter con un `cadenaoriginal.charAt(i) [i=contador del bucle for])`, si el carácter es igual a un espacio en blanco, omite y va a la siguiente cadena, si no es igual al espacio entonces concatena el carácter a la cadena nueva resultante.